# Loading a registration free COM object from a server with SilverLight

Tags: silverlight, com, silverlight-5.0

I have a working prototype that can download managed code via the AssemblyPart loader, but I don't see a direct way to load a native DLL or COM object.  The closest bit of information I've found for loading native code into memory via a stream is to [create your own loader](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/).  Going from that into the raw methods of accessing a COM object seems to be a bit excessive.

**Background:** the application is a signed business application running under elevated privileges.  I need to run a 3rd party COM object that provides integration features needed by the business.  I would like to avoid the deployment challenges associated with installing and maintaining the COM component at the desktops.  We are running in both in and out of browser modes.

Note we are using SilverLight 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy we've chosen to take involves downloading a wrapper for the COM object in the form of an application that contains the COM object.  The application will be downloaded and then executed.  This avoids an installation process and supports server side updating.